# How to deactivate trackpoint but keep button operation on Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme?

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, mouse-buttons

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Extreme and when I type the cursor moves diagonally up or down. This is extremelly anoying and the problem is located on the trackpoint.

When I deactivate it I have no issues. The problem is that Windows 10 automatically deactivates the two very useful buttons as well.

In the mouse settings I do not have any "Thinkpad" tabs as seen on the web. The synaptics driver seems to be installed in the system.

I cannot find info on how to deactivate only the red trackpoint. Any help woul be greatly appreciated!